# Twitter - Time Zone of the Tweeet

Tags: twitter, twitterizer

What is the time zone used for tweets in Twitter API?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The timezone of each tweet is automatically converted to the local timezone. If you need UTC, you can use the .ToUniversalTime() method, for example:
`myTweet.CreatedDate.ToUniversalTime();`

Comment: Thank you Rick. This is useful.

Comment: Note that these days, the REST API returns created_at in UTC

Comment: I believe that's always been the case. It is .NET that converts the date to local time.

Answer (score 7):

The created_at field for a tweet in the Twitter REST API gives the timestamp in UTC.

If a user has configured their timezone with Twitter, the utc_offset field gives you the difference in seconds between their timezone and UTC.  So,

`"utc_offset":-28800`

corresponds to -28800/3600 = -8 hours from UTC.

There are a [couple](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/twitter-development-talk/RCKDP1y5mAY) of [suggestions](http://code.google.com/p/twitter-api/issues/detail?id=864) that this doesn't get adjusted for daylight savings.

Answer (score 0):

Time zone is in the user settings under delivery options.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I think It is impossible. Twitter does not store any information related to local timezone. I found that user.utc_offset are always null.